# element.focus is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

***element.focus*** id not working. Even after value is true.

```
workSpaceModule.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
  return {

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
      scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
        console.log('value=',value);

        if(value === true) { 

          $timeout(function() {
            console.log('element=',element[0]);
            window.setTimeout(function ()
            {
                element[0].focus();
                 element[0].select();
            }, 0);
          });
        }
      });
      element.bind('blur', function() {
        console.log('blur')
        scope.$apply(model.assign($scope, false));
      })
    }
  };
});
// HTML
<input type="text" id="txtWorkspace"
ng-model="workSpace.name" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Name your workspace" 
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && createWorkSpace()" 
focus-me="myfocus" />
```

Comment: <span class="m-t-lg">
                          <a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="myfocus=true;">
                          <img src="images/add-workspace-icon.png"></a>
                          </span>
                          
                          <h5 class="font-bold m-t-md">
                            <a href="#modal" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="myfocus=true;" class="text-info">Create a new workspace</a>
                          </h5>

Comment: code working fine, are you sure your module is correctly loaded?

Comment: yes it is working fine now...thank you